# Rings with isomorphic center not necessarily Morita equivalent

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

a friend asked me this question; after a bit of searching, I'm still unable to answer it.

> **Question**
>   Are there two rings with isomorphic centers which are not Morita equivalent?

Our first method of attack was to use that Morita equivalent rings have isomorphic $K_0,K_1,$ and $K_2$. However, Bass proved in '64 that f.g. projective modules over the monoid ring (over a PID) on a free monoid are free, so $K_0$ doesn't distinguish $F\langle x,y\rangle$ from $F$. I know that $K_1(F)$ is the units of $F$, but I'm having a hard time finding any computations of the $K$-theory of noncommutative rings like $F\langle x,y\rangle$.

It would be awesome if there was a counter-example proved using low degree $K$-theory, but any counter-example would work (assuming one exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field with nontrivial [Brauer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group), and let $A$ be a central simple algebra over $k$ representing a nonzero class in its Brauer group. Then $k$ and $A$ are not Morita equivalent, but both have center $k$. For example you can take $k = \mathbb{R}, A = \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Oh excellent, thanks! Is $K_1(\mathbb H)$ by chance $\mathbb C^\times$?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to compute $K_1$ of anything.

Comment: Ok, np. I think at least this paper shows that $K_2$ is different: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869379903375

Comment: It's much easier just to prove directly that they are not Morita equivalent. The category of $\mathbb{H}$-modules cannot be equivalent to the category of $\mathbb{R}$-modules because in the former category every nonzero object has noncommutative endomorphism ring, but this isn't true in the latter.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much. Just for completeness sake, in page 200 of the $K$-book Weibel cites that $K_1(\mathbb H) \cong \mathbb R^\times_+$.

Answer (score 3):

The $\mathbb R-\mathbb H$ example is very accessible, but I thought I would add a few more that come to mind where the differences in the rings are more striking.

For example, the center of the upper triangular matrices $U_n(\mathbb F)$ for a field $\mathbb F$ and $n >1$ consists of the constant diagonal matrices (just like in the full matrix ring), so its center is isomorphic to $\mathbb F$. But the ring of upper triangular matrices has a nontrivial Jacobson radical, unlike that of $\mathbb F$. Since having Jacobson radical zero is a Morita invariant property, these two rings can't be Morita equivalent.

For another example, consider the endomorphism ring $E$ of a countably infinite dimensional $\mathbb F$ vector space $V$. This can be thought of as the row finite matrices in the set of matrices with sides indexed by $\mathbb N$, and just like for finite square matrix rings, the center is the set of constant diagonal matrices, so the center is isomorphic to $\mathbb F$. This ring is Jacobson semisimple, but now it is not Noetherian on either side, nor is it even simple. For both these reasons, it can't be Morita equivalent to $\mathbb F$. In fact, you can even show that $E$ is the only ring Morita equivalent to $E$!

Comment: For someone with less experience with non-commutative algebra like me, these examples are a lot more accessible!

Comment: @MorganRogers Wow thanks, I'm glad it was helpful!